# CNAME - MX Records (Google Apps)

Tags: domain-name-system, gmail, cname-record, mx-record

I need to know if I can "CNAME" older domains to a new domain names so that BOTH email addresses and browser requests will still work.

I say this is because I will need emails for email1@old-domain1.co.uk/email1@old-domain2.co.uk to automatically go to email1@new-domain.co.uk.

The reason for this is because the UK company I work for are re-branding with a ".com" domain and I need the older .co.uk domains and email addresses to still work. We are also at the same time moving from an Exchange 2000 solution to a Google Apps cloud-based solution.

Answer (score 1):

Certainly. The only trick is that MX records do not support CNAME records. You need to:

1. Add a CNAME record(s) for
   www.olddomain.co.uk that points to
   www.newdomain.com.
2. Add a host record
   for the root of olddomain.co.uk that
   points to the same IP as the root of
   newdomain.com
3. Add MX records that
   point to the same host names as the
   MX records for newdomain.com.
4. Configure your mail server (google
   apps) to accept emails for all teh
   domains in question. This last bit
   is easy with something like Exchange
   that you control completely; I am
   sure a solution is possible with
   Google Apps (although it may require
   multiple domains being set up with
   forwarding for each email address,
   which will be a pain to manage).

Answer (score 1):

Its quite simple to add domain aliases in Google Apps, but it requires the Business edition. The free edition does not support domain aliases.

1. Sign in to the Google Apps administrator control panel.
2. From the menu at the top of the page, select Domain settings.
3. Choose the Domain names tab.
4. Click Add a domain or a domain alias.
5. Enter the name of the domain to add to your account.
6. You must own the domain name, and it must not be registered as part of any other Google Apps account.
7. To add the domain as a domain alias for your primary domain, select the check box Make this domain an alias of my primary domain.

[via.](http://www.google.com/support/a/bin/answer.py?answer=53295)